# In Spring, @RequestParameter annotation not accepting boolean for defaultValue argument, it only works with string URL request parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This question is related to Spring MVC method I have defined below:

The value for the writeToRead parameter should be true or false. I expect the enduser calling my service to append to the url: `localhost:8080/index/someendpoint/sometype` the following request parameter: `?writeToRead=true` otherwise it should default to false if user doesn't append the parameter to the end of the url string. The problem is, the `defaultValue=false` doesn't seem to be acceptable in the `@RequestParameter` annotation. It looks like it only accepts string types rather than the boolean type I'm using. I could make defaultValue="false" but really, that's not a boolean. It's a string. How should I approach this? I can't use string alternatives (like "Y" or "N") to solve this problem because of method overloaded definition conflicts. How can I do this with booleans?  Thank you in advance!

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index/{endpoint}/{type}", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=kCompressed, produces=kProducesType)
@ResponseBody
public String indexData(@PathVariable(value="endpoint") String endpoint, @PathVariable(value="type") String type, 
                        @RequestParam(value="writeToRead", defaultValue=false) boolean writeToRead,                 
                        @RequestBody byte[] body, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    logger.debug("In indexData for endpoint " + endpoint);

    String bodyStr = decompress(body);
    return indexController.indexData(endpoint, type, bodyStr, writeToRead, getSecurityContextProvider(request));
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Declaring it as

```
@RequestParam(value="writeToRead", defaultValue="false")
```

is the appropriate thing to do. Request parameters are character strings, nothing else. You can parse them and give them the semantics you want or require (ex. booleans), but, at the base, they are just strings.

Comment: How is that? If the end user does not append `?writeToRead=true` to the end of the url, the value of writeToRead in the method definition will become "false" because of the defaultValue but that doesn't work. Since the parameter to the `indexData()` accepts a boolean (false) not the string "false".

Comment: @TazMan Spring uses a number of default and custom converters to convert from String values to the types you specify. So it will do something like `Boolean.parseBoolean("false")` and pass the returned value as an argument to your method. Similarly, if your parameter was a `long`, you could do `defaultValue="12345"`.

Comment: great. So that means I don't have to do anything like `Boolean.parseBoolean("false")` on my end. Spring will resolve it internally with out me noticing.

Comment: @TazMan Right. It will work for primitive types and enums, but for any reference types (other than `String`), you will usually have to register your own converter.

Comment: @TazMan You're very welcome. Because I spend so much time there, [here's](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam) the link to the documentation that explains this behaviour.